# How to setup DFP in React Native app

Tags: react-native, google-dfp

Can't setup google doubleclick publisher ads in React Native app.

I tried to use this plugin: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob, but it doesn't work. It works, if i add admob code, but doesn't work with DFP code.

I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything helpful. Write an issue to react-native-admob plugin github page, but noone answers.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [version 1](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/tree/1.x) instead - version 2 is still in beta.

Comment: Do you know how to use this plugin?Which code should i provide from doubleclick how to create banner for mobile ad and how to config a banner?

Comment: After you've [installed](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/tree/1.x#installation) it, you have to go to [admob.com](https://apps.admob.com/v2/home), set up an app for their respective platforms and then set up what types of ads you want. After setting up an ad (banner ad for example), copy it's ad unit ID and pass it as a prop to it's respective ad element (e.g. < AdMobBanner adUnitID={adUnitID} />)

Comment: This works on admob but i need publisher banners which must be created here: https://google.com/dfp right?I need to use doubleclick ads not admob. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Apparently [DoubleClick ads are now called Google Ad Manager](https://www.blog.google/technology/ads/new-advertising-brands/?utm_source=dclk.com&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=notification) and if you visit [their website](https://admanager.google.com/home/), it's one of the most out of character Google websites I have ever seen. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have created library that uses WebView to display DFP. It's easy to implement and working fine in my project. Here is the link: [react-native-google-publisher-tag](https://github.com/shukerullah/react-native-google-publisher-tag)

It's also support fluid and multiple sizes with unit targeting.